# How to show/hide element in *ngFor array, without touching this Array?

Tags: angular, ngfor

1.Hello.There are a lot of answers how to show/hide element, attaching to each element of iterated array an property which we change on true/false.

```
 <button  (click)="attachmentHide = !attachmentHide"></button>
<itemComp [itemsArray]='item.children' class="col-sm-offset-1 subItemHiden" [class.subItemsShow] = 'showSubItem'></itemComp>
```

so every time when we list each element of array it creates item.showSubItem property. In this case our array has been changed.

But what to do if i want show/hide this items, but WITHOUT editing main array.It's important because I check this array for equal at the begining.
there was answer to create a var which is not related to array, but how to create var for every element to show/hide every element separately?

**update:**

```
<div class="row col-sm-offset-1"  *ngFor="let item of itemsArray">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row assignedItem">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign " title="sub items"  (click)= "showSubItem = !showSubItem"></span>

            <div class=" itemName" title="State:{{item.state}},Type: {{item.type}}">{{item.name}}</div>
            <!--users component-->

        <!--show subItems-->
        <itemComp [itemsArray]='item.children' class="col-sm-offset-1 subItemHiden" [class.subItemsShow] = 'showSubItem'></itemComp>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
export class ItemComponent {
@Input() itemsArray: Array<Object>;

constructor () {}
}
```

**update 2:**

I've initialised array with i=false in home.ts:

```
viewNodes(result) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.myRes =  result;
        this.showSubItemsArr = this.myRes.content.map(i => false);
        this.itemsParentArray = this.myRes.content;
        console.log( this.showSubItemsArr );
        this.showAssigned = true;
    }, 3000);
}
```

after I sent it to child component, in html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!--show item-->
    <itemComp [showSubItems]="showSubItemsArr" [itemsArray]='itemsParentArray'  ></itemComp>
</div>
```

than I try to view items with showSubItems[idx].

```
    <div class="row col-sm-offset-1"  *ngFor="let item of itemsArray let idx=index">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row assignedItem">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign " title="sub items"  (click)= "showSubItem = !showSubItem"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" title="attached docs" (click)="attachmentHide = !attachmentHide"></span>
            <div class=" itemName" title="State:{{item.state}},Type: {{item.type}}">{{item.name}}</div>
            <!--users component-->
            <usersComp [userArray]="item.assignment"></usersComp>
        </div> {{showSubItems}}
        <!--attachment component-->
        <attachmentComp class="col-sm-offset-1" [attachmentsArray]='item.attachments' *ngIf="attachmentHide"></attachmentComp>
        <!--show subItems-->
        <itemComp [itemsArray]='item.children' class="col-sm-offset-1 subItemHiden" [class.subItemsShow] = 'showSubItems[idx]'></itemComp>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it show error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

but when I render all `{{showSubItems}}` array it displays `false,false,false` without problems.

It seams like `idx` value is not ready for second iteration. Sorry can't use plunker( working on it).

Comment: Where is your `*ngFor`?

Comment: I've updated.thank you.

Comment: You didn't update the click handler the way I showed in my answer (`(click)= "showSubItems[idx] = !showSubItems[idx]"`). Is the error before you click the button?

Comment: The `setTimeout(...)` looks bad and is bad practice. What do you need it for? Try setting `showSubItems to an initial value like `showSubItems = [];`

Comment: Yes. the error  apears before.
Errors apear when i use [idx] to use current element of array. 
thank you very much for  your comment. I'll work on it. setTimeout i need because it shows some errors when there are no data. But i will work on using without it.

Comment: You can try if `ngOnChanges()` works for you. It is called every time an `@Input()` is updated (by Angular binding, not when you code updates the property directly). Note: `ngOnChanges()` isn't called when you modify an array after you passed it to a binding `[someProp]="someArray"`.

Comment: I found i problem, why error  "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"   was appearing:
   when I wanted to use showSubItems[idx] at the begining of loading template , array did not uploaded when page did, so there was no index in this array.So I've put next thing:  
      @Input() showSubItems: Array = [];. Now your advice works fine. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `this.itemsArray` data is available we create another array `showSubItems` that gets one entry (default `false`) for each item in `this.itemsArray`:

```
constructor() { // or somewhere else where `this.itemsArray` data is already set
  this.showSubItems = this.itemsArray.map(i => false);
}
```

We use the `index` feature of `ngFor` and declare an `idx` variable. With this variable we reference the item in the `this.showSubItems` array item at the same index as the one from `this.itemsArray`

```
<div class="row col-sm-offset-1"  *ngFor="let item of itemsArray let idx=index">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row assignedItem">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign " title="sub items"  (click)= "showSubItems[idx] = !showSubItems[idx]"></span>

            <div class=" itemName" title="State:{{item.state}},Type: {{item.type}}">{{item.name}}</div>
            <!--users component-->

        <!--show subItems-->
        <itemComp [itemsArray]='item.children' class="col-sm-offset-1 subItemHiden" [class.subItemsShow] = 'showSubItems[idx]'></itemComp>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only question:
I've imported import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

but browser shows: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
what can it be?

Comment: As mentioned `this.showSubItems = this.itemsArray.map(i => false);` is to be executed when `this.itemsArray` is set. If it is `undefined` you'll get this error when `this.itemsArray.map(...)` is executed. I can't see from your question where `this.itemsArray` is set, therefore I used the constructor as example.

Comment: If you pass something to an input `[xxx]="..."`, `xxx` is not available immediately when the component is created (only after `ngOnChanges` is called or `ngOnChanges`), especially when you use `setTimeout`. You need to guard against `showSubItems` not yet set like `[class.subItemsShow] = 'showSubItems && showSubItems[idx]'`